# URL with hash behaves differently when used with window.open() method without window.location.href property

Tags: javascript, hash, navigation

I am not familiar with Javascript, and would be grateful if you could enlighten me regarding the following observation.

I have this Javascript function which should navigate to a page with param string appended. For example:

```
savebuttonClick() {

       window.open(encodeURI("/lightning/n/Test_Win_Open_Child#Id=123"),"_self");    
     

    }
```

However, the above script would navigate to the correct URL, but with a blank page displayed. The page would load its content as expected, upon a manually refresh of the browser tab.

Changing the scripts by constructing the URL with the window.location.href property first before navigating with the window.open() method would addressed the issue. The page will be displayed as expected, and the parameter (Id)'s value (123) will be passed to the page:

```
       window.location.href = encodeURI("/lightning/n/Test_Win_Open_Child#Id=123");
       window.open(window.location.href,"_self");
```

Or, replacing the hash(#) with question mark (?) would also work:

```
       window.open(encodeURI("/lightning/n/Test_Win_Open_Child?Id=123"),"_self");
```

Can someone please help explain the above observation?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've supplied a relative URL to `window.open`:

```
encodeURI("/lightning/n/Test_Win_Open_Child#Id=123")
```

which evaluates to "/lightning/n/Test_Win_Open_Child#Id=123" in any case.

`window.open` opens a page with the url "about:blank" by default. A relative url  applied to `about:blank` is still a blank page: exactly what you first see.

Here's the tricky bit.

1. The base url of a page opened with `about: blank` is the url of the opener. Case in point, if you `document.write` content to an opened page that contains a link such as `#` to go to the top of the document, *taking the link opens the **opener** page* at the top, instead of scrolling to the top of the **opened** page. (IMHO this a bug but I digress).
2. If you reload the opened page, the **relative** url of the opened page is resolved against the url of the opener page, as reported in the post.

**Predictive confirmation**

Supply an absolute url to `window.open` instead of a relative url.

**PostScipt**

Using the hash tag in a URL provides a fragment identifier to browsers, but **does not** require them to reload a page from the server.

Providing a query component, introduced by `?`, **does** require browsers to reload the page from the server, which requires an absolute URL. Resolving a relative url against the opened pages base url (not "about:blank") would cause reloading the opened page with the *intended* URL.

Comment: Thanks Traktor for explaining the expected behavior of window.open(), it helps to understand why it shows blank page on the first redirect, and only load the page upon the next page reload.

However, I am still not able to understand, why it would work when window.location.href is involved, since we are still navigating to the same url (both scenarios were also encoded with encodeURI()) using window.open(). 


Would you be able to explain this behavior please? Thank you

Comment: Setting `window.location.href` to a url relative to its existing content would have to resolve the relative url in the process to ensure the location represents an absolute url. If you then use it to open a child window, you are opening it with an absolute url which works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the issue with the original script is that the `encodeURI()` function only encodes special characters in a URL, such as spaces and question mark. However, it does not encode the hash symbol (#), which is used to specify the location of a fragment identifier in a URL.

When you use `window.open()` to navigate to a URL with a fragment identifier, the browser will not reload the page, but instead just scroll to the specified location on the current page. This is why you see a blank page displayed.

By using `window.location.href` to construct the URL first and then passing it to `window.open()`, you are encoding the hash symbol (#) as well as any other special characters in the URL. This ensures that the browser will reload the page with the specified fragment identifier.

Alternatively, you can replace the hash symbol (#) with a question mark (?) in the URL. This will make the browser treat the parameter as a query parameter instead of a fragment identifier, which will cause the page to reload with the specified parameter value.

Comment: Thanks Florent. I am trying to understand what is the difference between using encodeURI() function with the URL, directly with window.open(), and constructing the url with window.location.href property first, since I am also using encodeURI() on the same URL? I would expect the encoded result to be the same, isn't it? Thank you